# Nested While and For loops not stopping in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

I am converting Markdown(.md) file into HTML using a Python 2.7 program. There is an instance, however, where a while loop is not exiting correctly and just looping through the same number over and over again.

```html
def link(line):
    link_list = []
    link_string = ''
    count = 0
    left_bracket = 0
    right_bracket = 0
    left_parenth = 0
    right_parenth = 0
    for char in line:
        link_list.append(char)
    while count < (len(link_list)):
        if link_list[count] == "[":
            left_bracket = count
            for x in link_list[left_bracket+1:]:
                if x == "]":
                    right_bracket = link_list.index(x)
                if x == "(":
                    left_parenth = link_list.index(x)
                if x == ")":
                    right_parenth = link_list.index(x)
                    break
            a_list = link_list[left_bracket+1:right_bracket]
            str1 = ''.join(a_list)
            href_list = link_list[left_parenth+1:right_parenth]
            str2 = ''.join(href_list)
            link_string = link_string + '<a href="' + str2 + '">' + str1 + '</a>'
            count = right_parenth +1
        if link_list[count] != "[":
            link_string = link_string + link_list[count]
            count += 1
    print link_string
link("lorem ipsum [inside bracket](URL LINK), [inside_bracket2](URL2)")
```

In this function, it is converting Markdown link formats to HTML link formats.

If you call the function with the argument below

```html
link("lorem ipsum [inside bracket](URL LINK")
```

it gives you the correct output. However, when you put more than one markdown link in a string, then the while loops and for loops do not function properly.

Comment: I can't get a result with the single string, script seems to get stuck at line `link_string = link_string + '<a href="' + str2 + '">' + str1 + '</a>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use **regex**. It will greatly reduce code.

```
import re
def link(line):
    return re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)', r'<a href="\2">\1</a>', line)

link("The biggest headliners usually perform at the Orpheum Theatre, the [Overture Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overture_Center), [Breese Stevens Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breese_Stevens_Field), the [Alliant Energy Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliant_Energy_Center), or the UW Theatre on campus.")
```

Output:

```
The biggest headliners usually perform at the Orpheum Theatre, the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overture_Center">Overture Center</a>, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breese_Stevens_Field">Breese Stevens Field</a>, the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliant_Energy_Center">Alliant Energy Center</a>, or the UW Theatre on campus.
```

Go ahead and try it out on Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/S3oFLH/1

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
            if x == "]":
                right_bracket = link_list.index(x)
            if x == "(":
                left_parenth = link_list.index(x)
            if x == ")":
                right_parenth = link_list.index(x)
                break
```

You're using the bracket/parenths as indexes, so you should directly pass x to them. By using link_list.index(x), it always returns the first character it finds from the left, and that's why your loop got stuck.